# How to safely cast nullable result from sqlreader to int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, sqldatareader, dbnull

I have a table which contains null values and I need to get data from the table using SqlDataReader. I can't figure out how I can safely cast DBNull to int.

I'm doing it in this way at the moment:

```
...
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
     int y = (reader["PublicationYear"] != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["PublicationYear"]) : 0;
     ...
}
...
```

but getting a `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.` when PublicationYear is null.

How can I get the value safely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should compare `reader["PublicationYear"]` to `DBNull.Value`, not `null`.

Answer (score 4):

`DBNull` is not the same as `null`. You should try something like this instead:

```
int y = (reader["PublicationYear"] != DBNull.Value) ? ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int ord = reader.GetOrdinal("PublicationYear");
int y = reader.IsDBNull(ord) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(ord);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
object obj = reader["PublicationYear"];
int y = Convert.IsDBNull(obj) ? 0 : (int)obj;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

`reader["PublicationYear"] != null`

to

`reader["PublicationYear"] != DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly check if the value returned is of type `DBNull`

```
while (reader.Read()) {
     int y = (!reader["PublicationYear"] is DBNull) ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["PublicationYear"]) : 0;
     ...
}
```

In fact, you can do this comparison by value as well as type:

```
reader["PublicationYear"] != DBNull.Value
```

In short - you can expect `DBNull` to be returned for nulls from the database, rather than null itself.

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative you can do the following.
as you are converting DBNull to 0, alter the procedure that does the select. so that the select itself returns zero for a null value.

snippet to demonstrate the idea

```
    SELECT ...
           ,ISNULL (PublicationYear, 0) as PublicationYear
           ...
    FROM sometable
```

advantage of this is that, no additional checking is needed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

That's the error: `(reader["PublicationYear"] != null)`
You should test for DBNull.Value....

Answer (score 1):

Change your test from `(reader["PublicationYear"] != null)` to `(reader["PublicationYear"] != DBNull.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Database null values should be compared with `DBNull.Value`:

```
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) 
{
     int y = (reader["PublicationYear"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(reader["PublicationYear"]) : 0;
     ...
}
```